# User customizable portal software

Tags: customization, portlet, portal

I am interested in portal software that allows a user to customize their experience by:
* Lay out the portlets as desired on the page
* Select which portlets to display

Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I should say Liferay is the best when it comes to Portal with personalization. It provides

1) User pages (private level)
2) User pages (public level, shared with others)
3) Communities (Now sites, group of pages, shared with several users)
4) Themes, color schemes (personalized to page level)
5) Page layouts (personlized to page level)
6) Permissions (can be set with level portal, site, group, user, page, portlet)

-- Felix

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with Microsoft related technologies, maybe someone else can complement with other vendors' \ Open source.

If your are using ASP.net 2.0 and above, it has the concept of "Web Parts" that allows a developer to build configurable, reusable components. This is a framework, so you still need to develop a solution using the concepts offered by the framework.

If you are not interested in developing the solution, MS has a product called "SharePoint Foundation" which is a FREE product (also has paid versions that are more enterprise oriented) that build on top of ASP.net, and provides implementation for those concepts (among many other features).
In SharePoint, a developer creates web part just like in asp.net, SP also allows easy creation of sites and pages. a user can add web parts to a page. web parts are distributed via the web parts gallery.
SharePoint also ships with a number of web parts, and there's a large community of SharePoint developers where you can find free open source web parts.
Also, in SP every user can personalize the layout of web parts in a page as he likes (you can disable this if you don't want to allow it).

Answer (score 0):

In the Java JSR-286 world, you should try [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) or [eXo Platform](http://www.exoplatform.com/company/en/home). These are really the best open source portals. They do what you are requiring.

And you can also take a look at IBM [Websphere Portal](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/portal/), or one of the multiple portals Oracle has bought.

[enter link description here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286)